# Replace two elements with their absolute difference and generate the minimum possible element in array

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of size n and I can apply any number of operations(zero included) on it. In an operation, I can take any two elements and replace them with the absolute difference of the two elements. We have to find the minimum possible element that can be generated using the operation. (n<1000)

> Here's an example of how operation works. Let the array be [1,3,4]. Applying operation on 1,3 gives [2,4] as the new array.

Ex: 2 6 11 3 => ans = 0

This is because 11-6 = 5 and 5-3 = 2 and 2-2 = 0

Ex:  20 6 4 => ans = 2

Ex: 2 6 10 14 => ans = 0

Ex: 2 6 10 => ans = 2

Can anyone tell me how can I approach this problem?

Edit:

We can use recursion to generate all possible cases and pick the minimum element from them. This would have complexity of O(n^2 !).

Another approach I tried is Sorting the array and then making a recursion call where the either starting from 0 or 1, I apply the operations on all consecutive elements. This will continue till their is only one element left in the array and we can return the minimum at any point in the recursion. This will have a complexity of O(n^2) but doesn't necessarily give the right answer.

Ex: 2 6 10 15 => (4 5) & (2 4 15) => (1) & (2 15) & (2 11) => (13) & (9). The minimum of this will be 1 which is the answer.

Comment: One approach is to try out everything and then pick the best option. Not the best approach but it works. What stops you from trying that out first? Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Also, it seems that there is a restriction you havent telled us yet. Namely that each number can only be used once. Else the results would be very different. But you just said "any of the numbers".

Comment: I think straightforward greedy approach would work here.

Comment: @Zabuza the numbers get replaced after being part of the "operation".

Comment: `Ex: 20 6 4 => ans = 2` is this correct? . I think it is 10?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya we can use the operation on 6,4. the array becomes [20,2] which has min element 2

Comment: @P.Gupta Let me know if my answer works for you. If it does not , tell me a case for it.

Comment: How big are the numbers?

Comment: I came up with complexity O(n * sum of all elements), I can explain it if you want, not sure if that's what you're looking for, but I have a feeling that it's some sort of NP problem.

Comment: @Maras Please do explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose two elements for the operation, you subtract the smaller one from the bigger one. So if you choose 1 and 7, the result is 7 - 1 = 6.

Now having 2 6 and 8 you can do:

8 - 2 -> 6 and then 6 - 6 = 0

You may also write it like this: 8 - 2 - 6 = 0

Let"s consider different operation: you can take two elements and replace them by their sum or their difference.

Even though you can obtain completely different values using the new operation, the absolute value of the element closest to 0 will be exactly the same as using the old one.

First, let's try to solve this problem using the new operations, then we'll make sure that the answer is indeed the same as using the old ones.

What you are trying to do is to choose two nonintersecting subsets of initial array, then from sum of all the elements from the first set subtract sum of all the elements from the second one. You want to find two such subsets that the result is closest possible to 0. That is an NP problem and one can efficiently solve it using pseudopolynomial algorithm similar to the knapsack problem in O(n * sum of all elements)

Each element of initial array can either belong to the positive set (set which sum you subtract from), negative set (set which sum you subtract) or none of them. In different words: each element you can either add to the result, subtract from the result or leave untouched. Let's say we already calculated all obtainable values using elements from the first one to the i-th one. Now we consider i+1-th element. We can take any of the obtainable values and increase it or decrease it by the value of i+1-th element. After doing that with all the elements we get all possible values obtainable from that array. Then we choose one which is closest to 0.

Now the harder part, why is it always a correct answer?
Let's consider positive and negative sets from which we obtain minimal result. We want to achieve it using initial operations. Let's say that there are more elements in the negative set than in the positive set (otherwise swap them).

What if we have only one element in the positive set and only one element in the negative set? Then absolute value of their difference is equal to the value obtained by using our operation on it.

What if we have one element in the positive set and two in the negative one?

1) One of the negative elements is smaller than the positive element - then we just take them and use the operation on them. The result of it is a new element in the positive set. Then we have the previous case.

2) Both negative elements are smaller than the positive one. Then if we remove bigger element from the negative set we get the result closer to 0, so this case is impossible to happen.

Let's say we have n elements in the positive set and m elements in the negative set (n <= m) and we are able to obtain the absolute value of difference of their sums (let's call it x) by using some operations. Now let's add an element to the negative set. If the difference before adding new element was negative, decreasing it by any other number makes it smaller, that is farther from 0, so it is impossible. So the difference must have been positive. Then we can use our operation on x and the new element to get the result.

Now second case: let's say we have n elements in the positive set and m elements in the negative set (n < m) and we are able to obtain the absolute value of difference of their sums (again let's call it x) by using some operations. Now we add new element to the positive set. Similarly, the difference must have been negative, so x is in the negative set. Then we obtain the result by doing the operation on x and the new element.

Using induction we can prove that the answer is always correct.